# Turn off touchpad, point stick

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I just installed 18.04.2 on an HP 8460W.  Typically on laptops I like to:

1. Turn off the touchpad when a USB mouse is connected
2. Turn off the little joystick in the middle of the keyboard (and its buttons nr the spacebar) ***forever***

How do I do either/both of these things in Ubuntu?  If it matters, I took the default Gnome-based desktop.

Out put of `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam [Fixed]: HP HD Web           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of `xinput --list-props 11`

```
    Device 'PS/2 Generic Mouse':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (283):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (284):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (285):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (286):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (287):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (288): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (289): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (290):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (291):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (292): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (293): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (294):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (295):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (296):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (297): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (298): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (268): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (269):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (270):    0, 0
    Device Node (271):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (272):    2, 1
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (299):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (300):   1
```

Output of `xinput --list-props 12`

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (301): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (302): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (303):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (304):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (305):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (306):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (307):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (308):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (283):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (284):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (309):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (310):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (285):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (286):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (287):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Accel Speed (292): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (293): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (297): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (298): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (268): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (269):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (270):    0, 0
    Device Node (271):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (272):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (299):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (300):   1
```

Output of `xinput --list-props 13`

```
Device 'HP WMI hotkeys':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (268): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (269):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (270):    0, 0
    Device Node (271):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (272):    0, 0
```

Comment: Not a key per se: a little rubber nubbin stuck between the keys.  And two mouse-like buttons.  All are working.

Comment: Hm, OK.  That's a start.  The joystick is all part of the same device, 12?

Comment: 12 disables the touchpad, 11 disables the joystick.  I will put disabling the hoystick in my startup because I *never* want that thing

Comment: two buttons for each, touchpad and joystick.  plus tapping the touchpad duplicates the function of the left (primary) button

Comment: two, plus a scroll wheel

Comment: Thanks for all your help (incl. the code edit).  I will check back here in an hour or two

Answer (score 0):

1. to Turn off the touchpad when a USB mouse is connected run the below command

   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'disabled-on-external-mouse'`

to reset the above command run the below command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events
```

2. To turnoff the little joystick.. you need to find out what is the ID for this joystick from `xinput` output and perhaps its required to disable meaningful ID's and see which one is the rite one..

from your `xinput` output it seems to be id 11 for joystick..

to disable this joystick run the below command

```
xinput --disable 11
```

above command will disable the joystick until you logout or reboot only..

to permanently disable it, add the command `xinput --disable 11` command in your startup application preferences list..