# Is there a way to toggle touchpad on/off with a command/keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchpad, gnome-control-center

Is there a way to toggle touchpad on/off with a command/keyboard shortcut?
I tried using this:

```
if $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled); then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled false; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true; fi
```

But it didn't work at all.

Comment: does your keyboard have toggle button/ key?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I want to bind te command to the shortcut. Most likely ctrl+shift+l

Comment: From what i see this question has already been answered, check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67718/how-do-i-disable-a-touchpad-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable a touchpad using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67718/how-do-i-disable-a-touchpad-using-the-command-line)

Comment: I tried those, the problem is I have thinkpad T440p with touchpad combined with trackpoint buttons, if I disable trackpad buttons will be also disabled. If I turn off touchpad in gnome control center it works though.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1147496/739431 check this one/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Work Around:

with the help of this post https://askubuntu.com/a/1140700/739431

install the xdotool package if not yet installed, `sudo apt install xdotool`

1. run `xmodmap -pke | grep TouchpadToggle`

example

```
pratap@i7:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep TouchpadToggle
keycode  71 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
pratap@i7:~$
```

2. run in terminal `xdotool key XF86TouchpadToggle` to check if the touchpad toggling is working?

[image]

3. Create your own shortcut Shift+Ctrl+I with custom command `xdotool sleep 1 key XF86TouchpadToggle` sleep value 0.5 may also work.. try it with your comfort..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | grep -q 'TouchpadOff.*1'; echo $?)
```

and

```
tp=$(synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | awk '{ print $3 }') && tp=$((tp==0)) && synclient TouchpadOff=$tp
```

both work for me in Xfce to toggle touchpad onn/off.

I use them with a shortcut associated with a script like

```
#!/bin/bash

synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | grep -q 'TouchpadOff.*1'; echo $?)
```

source - [here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/24256/toggle-the-touchpad-on-or-off)

Comment: The accepted answer will work if XF86TouchpadToggle works. If not, then this is the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
On my laptop I can toggle on/off the touch-pad using the key F5.
try it on your laptop if it's not works then try pressing **Fn** + **F5** 
(F5 or the key which your laptop use). look at the icons on your keyboard.

Comment: The OP's machine has no such shortcuts according to the comment above.