# How to turn touch pad back on using keyboard

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, touchpad

I managed to turn off my touch pad and looking for a way to turn it on.

I tried windows key and managed to search settings. But display is selected and could not figure out how to navigate between settings.

My ultimate solution was to connect another usb mouse and switch on turn pad. But I more interested in switching on or off touch pad in GUI using keyboard or from terminal.

I experimented with tab key when mouse was selected and looks like I can turn it on using tab and space combo after some experimentation. However UI, at least on my machine does not provide any visual cues about which item is currently selected and just beeps when I hit tab or spacebar

Pratap commented about a possible solution and it will (should) work, but that involves installing something that is not part of standard distribution and should be easily achievable in UI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to toggle touchpad on/off with a command/keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165445/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-touchpad-on-off-with-a-command-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: @PRATAP, that sounds like a possible solution. But it's basically saying you have to install something which any UI should be able handle by default. Why can't we navigate across devices list like Displays/Keyboard on left hand side and select button using standard tabs and space - general universal UI standard

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/863746/keyboard-shortcut-to-toggle-enable-disable-laptop-touchpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to toggle the touch pad on and off via keyboard keys to control UI, it seems to be theming Issue..

for practice, change your Appearence theme to Highcontrast or Highcontrast Inverse

and then run `gnome-control-center mouse` and use TAB for around 9 or 10 Times to reach to Touchpad Toggle On Off Area.. then pressing Enter will toogle..

[image]

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, but I had figured out this as stated in the question. Default theme is problematic and I could not figure out a way to move across devices - may be it's theme problem again